Powershell : How to include the root directory while creating a zip using a function
Code:
Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

function Compress-CompatibleArchive {

    param (
        [String[]] $Path,
        [String] $DestinationPath
    )

    $zipfilename = $DestinationPath
    $sourcedir = $Path

    $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir,$zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Compress-CompatibleArchive

Command to execute :
.\PublishPlugin.ps1 C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Pictures\testing C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Pictures\zipdest\1.zip

O/P : This only zips the content inside the testing folder.
What I want is to include the testing folder along with the content.
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

If you take a look at the docs for [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory you will see the 4th parameter is called includeBaseDirectory, set that to $true and it will include the directory in the archive.
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir,$zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)

becomes
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir,$zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $true)

